# Excel: referencing a chart as ChartObjects & Chart vs Shapes

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I ran into a wall setting minimum- and maximumscale properties of a chart's secondary axis - kept getting an "object does not have this property" error. I fixed it, but I'd like to know how.

After too many hours of googling and trying different options (Three. Three stupid hours), I arbitrarily decided to reference the chart by way of the Shapes collection instead of the ChartObjects collection, and that worked.

So, good:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue,xlSecondary).MinimumScale = cMin
```

and bad:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue,xlSecondary).MinimumScale = cMin
```

but I *was* able to set other properties. E.g., the following line of code worked:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue,xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Text = "Current (A)"
```

From the MSDN documentation, both **Shapes(1)** and **ChartObjects(1)** return a **Chart** object, yet I couldn't access all properties when I accessed the Chart via the ChartObjects collection. That is, I am able to set all properties within the Axes method when I set the chart as

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Chart
```

but not if I set the chart as

```
Dim cht as Chart
Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
```

So my question is, why this discrepancy? Is this some hidden nuance of the VBA syntax, or more likely a foible of my machine?

Excel 2013 on a Windows 7 box

Comment: `Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart` works fine for me.  I think you need to set only one axis value at a time like this: `cht.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 10`

Comment: @portland-runner and dpbont, what are your versions of Excel?

Comment: There should be no difference between these assuming there are no other shapes or charts on the page.  I have always used `ChartObjects` (and never `Shapes`) and have not had this problem doing very similar things as you're doing.  What happens if you `Set` a reference to the `Axis` before you try and change the properties?  E.g.: `Dim ax as Axis: Set ax = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)`.

Comment: @PortlandRunner, the double axis reference is needed to get to the secondary value axis.  OP is using normal/correct syntax for that.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - 2013, on Windows 7. Edited original post to show.

Comment: @Byron - thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try when I'm back at work Monday. In case it's important, I'm also doing all this inside a With statement ("With cht \n\r   .Axes(...)..."). Trying it both using and not using a With statement gave the same original results, though, as did "ActiveSheet.ChartObjects..." vs "cht.Axes...".

Comment: @Byron - it worked to use ChartObjects when I set a reference to the axis, as you suggested. Any idea why that is?

Re: other objects... There's a table on another worksheet in the workbook, but no other charts or shapes. The sub exists in one workbook that has a form control button to execute the sub, which opens a CSV, does "Save As" to .xlsx, converts the data to a table, then creates the chart to plot a couple columns of data (all within the former CSV-turned-XLSX). It's a little convoluted, but not terrifically so.

Comment: I am not sure.  My general tendency when working with `Charts` is to create references to variables.  I have always done it so that Intellisense works, but I think it is good practice to tell VBA what you expect objects to contain.  That said, I have no idea why going through `Shapes` vs. `ChartObjects` makes a difference on this `Axis` property which is several levels removed from the source.